# Error in javascript Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have done drag and drop of popup in JavaScript and it is dragged in all directions properly but down.MouseUp event is not triggered properly when I drag the popup towards down.So that it is moving even though I released mouse. I am really screwed up with this bug.Please help..I have to resolve it urgently....

Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">

<style>
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
iframe{
  width:800px;
  height:500px;
}
img{border:none;}

.parentDisabled
{
 width:100%;
 height:100%
 background-color:red;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:block;
 border:1px solid blue;
}
#popup{
   position:absolute;
   width:800px;
   height:500px;
   border:2px solid #999188;  
  display:none;
 }

 #header{
 padding-right:0px;
 width:800px;
 }

 #close{
  cursor:hand;  
  width:15px;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  padding:2px 2px 0px 0px;
 }

 #move{
 cursor:move;
 background:#999188;
 width:800px;
 line-height:10px;
 }

 #container{

 }
 .navigate{
  border:1px solid black ;
  background:#CC00FF;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:hand;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:150px;
 }

</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div onClick="showPopUp('w3schools');" class="navigate">W3Schools</div>
<div onClick="showPopUp('yahoo');" class="navigate">Yahoo</div>
<div onClick="showPopUp('linkedin');" class="navigate">LinkedIn</div>
<div onClick="showPopUp('vistex');" class="navigate">Vistex</div>

<div id="popup">
       <div id="header">
        <span id="move"></span>
        <span id="close"><img src="close_red.gif" onClick="closePopUp()" alt="Close"/></span>   
       </div> 

      <div id="container">
          <iframe name="frame" id="Page_View" frameborder=0>
              page cannot be displayed
          </iframe>
      </div>

    </div>
</BODY>

<script>

var popUpEle=null;

function showPopUp(value,evt)
{
 evt = evt ? evt : window.event;
 var left=evt.clientX;
 var top=evt.clientY;

 popUpEle = document.getElementById('popup');
 if(popUpEle)
 {
  closePopUp();
  var url= "http://www."+value+".com";  
  document.getElementById('Page_View').src=url;

  popUpEle.style.left=left;
  popUpEle.style.top=top;
  popUpEle.style.filter="revealTrans( transition=1, duration=1)";
  popUpEle.filters.revealTrans( transition=1, duration=1).Apply();
  popUpEle.filters.revealTrans( transition=1, duration=1).Play();
  popUpEle.style.display="inline";
 }
}
function closePopUp(){
 if(popUpEle)
 {
  popUpEle.style.filter="revealTrans( transition=0, duration=4)";
  popUpEle.filters.revealTrans( transition=0, duration=5).Apply();
  popUpEle.filters.revealTrans( transition=0, duration=5).Play();
  popUpEle.style.display="none";

 }
}

  var dragApproved=false;
  var DragHandler = {

    // private property.
    _oElem : null,

    // public method. Attach drag handler to an element.
    attach : function(oElem) {
        oElem.onmousedown = DragHandler._dragBegin;
        // callbacks
        oElem.dragBegin = new Function();
        oElem.drag = new Function();
        oElem.dragEnd = new Function();
        return oElem;
    },
    // private method. Begin drag process.
    _dragBegin : function(e) {

        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem = this;

        if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.left))) { oElem.style.left = '0px'; }
        if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.top))) { oElem.style.top = '0px'; }

        var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
        var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

        e = e ? e : window.event;

       if (e.pageX || e.pageY) 
       {
        oElem.mouseX = e.pageX;
        oElem.mouseY = e.pageY;
       }
       else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)     {
        oElem.mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft+ document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        oElem.mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop+ document.documentElement.scrollTop;
       }

        document.onmousemove = DragHandler._drag;
        document.onmouseup = DragHandler._dragEnd;  
        return false;
    },
    // private method. Drag (move) element.
    _drag : function(e) {

        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;

        var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
        var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

        e = e ? e : window.event;

       var clientXTmp,clientYTmp;
       if (e.pageX || e.pageY) 
       {
        clientXTmp = e.pageX;
        clientXTmp = e.pageY;
       }
       else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)     {
        clientXTmp = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft+ document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        clientYTmp = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop+ document.documentElement.scrollTop;
       }

        var tmpX = x + (clientXTmp - oElem.mouseX);
        var tmpY = y + (clientYTmp - oElem.mouseY);

        if(tmpX<=0){tmpX = 0;}
        if(tmpY<=0){tmpY = 0;}

        oElem.style.left = tmpX + 'px';
        oElem.style.top  = tmpY + 'px';

        oElem.mouseX = clientXTmp;
        oElem.mouseY = clientYTmp;
        return false;

    },
    // private method. Stop drag process.
    _dragEnd : function() 
     {
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        DragHandler._oElem = null;
    }
}
DragHandler.attach(document.getElementById('popup'));</script>

</HTML>
```

Comment: make a fiddle please on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: what is the use of jsfiddle. I did that in jsfiddle but I didnt get any  error.

Answer (score 0):

First, your script didn't work in firefox or chrome so I did some changes.
Second, there's a limitation when moving the mouse very fast over the iframe. It seems that when the mouse is over an iframe, the 'mousemove' event isn't fired.

I inserted some fixes to your code and here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>New Document </title>
<meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
<meta name="Author" content="">
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<style>
    body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    iframe
    {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    img
    {
        border: none;
    }

    .parentDisabled
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100% background-color:red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    #popup
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        border: 2px solid #999188;
        display: none;
    }

    #header
    {
        padding-right: 0px;
        width: 800px;
        height:20px;
        background:#d8d8d8;
        cursor:move;
    }

    #close
    {
        cursor: hand;
        width: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        padding: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    }

    #move
    {
        cursor: move;
        background: #999188;
        width: 800px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }

    #container
    {
    }
    .navigate
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: #CC00FF;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: hand;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div onclick="showPopUp('w3schools', event);" class="navigate">
    W3Schools</div>
<div onclick="showPopUp('yahoo', event);" class="navigate">
    Yahoo</div>
<div onclick="showPopUp('linkedin', event);" class="navigate">
    LinkedIn</div>
<div onclick="showPopUp('vistex', event);" class="navigate">
    Vistex</div>
<div id="popup">
    <div id="header">
        <span id="move"></span><span id="close">
            <img src="close_red.gif" onclick="closePopUp()" alt="Close" /></span>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <iframe name="frame" id="Page_View" frameborder="0">page cannot be displayed </iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='log'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popUpEle = null;
var isIE = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1;

function showPopUp(value, evt)
{
    evt = evt ? evt : window.event;
    var left = evt.clientX;
    var top = evt.clientY;

    popUpEle = document.getElementById('popup');
    if (popUpEle)
    {
        closePopUp();
        var url = "http://www." + value + ".com";
        document.getElementById('Page_View').src = url;

        popUpEle.style.left = left;
        popUpEle.style.top = top;
        popUpEle.style.filter = "revealTrans( transition=1, duration=1)";
        if (isIE)
        {
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 1, duration = 1).Apply();
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 1, duration = 1).Play();
        }
        popUpEle.style.display = "block";
    }
}
function closePopUp()
{
    if (popUpEle)
    {
        popUpEle.style.filter = "revealTrans( transition=0, duration=4)";
        if (isIE)
        {
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 0, duration = 5).Apply();
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 0, duration = 5).Play();
        }
        popUpEle.style.display = "none";

    }
}

var DragHandler = {

    // private property.
    _oElem: null,

    _dragElement: null,

    // public method. Attach drag handler to an element.
    attach: function (oElem)
    {
        oElem.onmousedown = DragHandler._dragBegin;
        // callbacks
        oElem.dragBegin = new Function();
        oElem.drag = new Function();
        oElem.dragEnd = new Function();
        return oElem;
    },
    // private method. Begin drag process.
    _dragBegin: function (e)
    {
        e = window.event || e;
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem = this;


        // saving current mouse position
        oElem.mouseX = e.clientX;
        oElem.mouseY = e.clientY;


        //            if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.left))) { oElem.style.left = '0px'; }
        //            if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.top))) { oElem.style.top = '0px'; }

        //            var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
        //            var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

        //            e = e ? e : window.event;

        //            if (e.pageX || e.pageY)
        //            {
        //                oElem.mouseX = e.pageX;
        //                oElem.mouseY = e.pageY;
        //            }
        //            else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)
        //            {
        //                oElem.mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        //                oElem.mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        //            }

        // saving the element which invoked the drag
        // to capture 'mouseout' event
        DragHandler._dragElement = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        DragHandler._dragElement.onmouseout = DragHandler._dragMouseOut;

        document.onmousemove = DragHandler._drag;
        document.onmouseup = DragHandler._dragEnd;
        return false;
    },

    _dragMouseOut: function (e)
    {
        e = window.event || e;

        //document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "mouseout!: " + e.clientX + "," + e.clientY + "<br/>";

        // calculating move by
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;
        var moveByX = e.clientX - oElem.mouseX;
        var moveByY = e.clientY - oElem.mouseY;

        //if (document.getElementById("log").offsetHeight > 100)
            //document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "mouseout x: " + moveByX + ", y:" + moveByY + "<br/>";

        // setting position
        var futureX = (x + moveByX);
        if (futureX < 0) futureX = 0;
        var futureY = (y + moveByY);
        if (futureY < 0) futureY = 0;
        oElem.style.left = futureX + 'px';
        oElem.style.top = futureY + 'px';

        oElem.mouseX = e.clientX;
        if (oElem.mouseX < 0) oElem.mouseX = 0;
        oElem.mouseY = e.clientY;
        if (oElem.mouseY < 0) oElem.mouseY = 0;
    },

    // private method. Drag (move) element.
    _drag: function (e)
    {
        e = window.event || e;
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "mousemove!!!<br/>";

        // current element position
        var x = oElem.offsetLeft;
        var y = oElem.offsetTop;

        // calculating move by
        var moveByX = e.clientX - oElem.mouseX;
        var moveByY = e.clientY - oElem.mouseY;

        //if (document.getElementById("log").offsetHeight > 100)
            //document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += "mouse move x: " + moveByX + ", y:" + moveByY + "<br/>";

        // setting position
        var futureX = (x + moveByX);
        if (futureX < 0) futureX = 0;
        var futureY = (y + moveByY);
        if (futureY < 0) futureY = 0;
        oElem.style.left = futureX + 'px';
        oElem.style.top = futureY + 'px';

        oElem.mouseX = e.clientX;
        if (oElem.mouseX < 0) oElem.mouseX = 0;
        oElem.mouseY = e.clientY;
        if (oElem.mouseY < 0) oElem.mouseY = 0;

        // canceling selection
        if (!isIE)
            return false;
        else
            document.selection.empty();

    },
    // private method. Stop drag process.
    _dragEnd: function ()
    {
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        DragHandler._oElem = null;

        DragHandler._dragElement.onmouseout = null;
        DragHandler._dragElement = null;
    }
}
   DragHandler.attach(document.getElementById('popup'));
   </script>
       </body></html>
```

Comment: Hi Omeriko, Thanks for your reply.I had included your piece of code at the end of mousedown and mousemove handlers and tried,but there was no change.I am getting the same bug..Please can you check that once...

Comment: Yes Omeriko..It doesnt work in other than IE,But it is enough to work in IE..Our product is compatible to IE only.So please check it in IE and let me know if there is any mistake.Or if you have any workable code for dragging of popup,please pass to me.

Comment: Hey, I took some parts from my working dragging code and inserted into your script. Please check it and tell me if it helped you.

Comment: Hi Omeriko,I am very thankful to you for your work.But the unfortunate thing is it is not working for me.Still the mouseUp event is not triggered sometimes.And one more doubt is what is the need to call dragMouseOut method on MouseOut event.On MouseOut event dragging is not required,dragging should be stopped,right!.Can you please check it in your IE browser and let me know....

Comment: And,What are the x and y values in _dragMouseOut method. I put offsetLeft and Top but it didnt work.But it works some what better if x and y are assigned to event.clientX and Y.But it behaves in different way...please check it once....

Comment: Hey, Before uploading the content I checked it in my IE9 browser. If you want we can talk on Skype?

Comment: Oh....is it, but for me its giving some syntax errors too..x and y values are undefined in _dragMouseOut() function..And I cant talk to you using Skype in my office,So Can I please chat through Yahoo messenger...!!! ramstheroyal@yahoo.co.in is my yahoo messenger id...

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont have yahoo messenger. We can chat in facebook, gtalk or skype

Comment: Ok...then send me request from your facebook account to ramstheroyal@gmail.com.I can add you then. I would like to tell you that I have modified my code,it works somewhat better now. Here is my code....

Comment: but it works in IE only..for my project its k.If you can do any modifications please let me know...

Comment: Cool.
I prefer we talk on google-talk (via gmail) since I'm not available on facebook during the day. my gmail account is omeriko1984@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<style>
    body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    iframe
    {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    img
    {
        border: none;
    }

    .parentDisabled
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100% background-color:red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    #popup
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 2px solid #999188;
        display: none;
    }

    #header
    {
        padding-right: 0px;
        width: 400px;
        height:20px;
        background:#d8d8d8;
        cursor:move;
    }

    #close
    {
        cursor: hand;
        width: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        padding: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    }

    #move
    {
        cursor: move;
        background: #999188;
        width: 400px;
        line-height: 10px;
    }

    #container
    {
    }
    .navigate
    {
        border: 1px solid black;
        background: #CC00FF;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: hand;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 150px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <div onclick="showPopUp('w3schools', event);" class="navigate">
    W3Schools</div>
<div onclick="showPopUp('yahoo', event);" class="navigate">
    Yahoo</div>
<div onclick="showPopUp('linkedin', event);" class="navigate">
    LinkedIn</div>
<div onclick="showPopUp('vistex', event);" class="navigate">
    Vistex</div>
<div id="popup">
    <div id="header">
        <span id="move"></span><span id="close">
            <img src="close_red.gif" onclick="closePopUp()" alt="Close" /></span>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <iframe name="frame" id="Page_View" frameborder="0">page cannot be displayed </iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='log'></div>

</body>
<script>
var popUpEle = null;
var isIE = navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1;

function showPopUp(value, evt)
{
    evt = evt ? evt : window.event;
    var left = evt.clientX;
    var top = evt.clientY;

    popUpEle = document.getElementById('popup');
    if (popUpEle)
    {
        closePopUp();
        var url = "http://www." + value + ".com";
        document.getElementById('Page_View').src = url;

        popUpEle.style.left = left;
        popUpEle.style.top = top;
        popUpEle.style.filter = "revealTrans( transition=1, duration=1)";
        if (isIE)
        {
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 1, duration = 1).Apply();
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 1, duration = 1).Play();
        }
        popUpEle.style.display = "block";
    }
}
function closePopUp()
{
    if (popUpEle)
    {
        popUpEle.style.filter = "revealTrans( transition=0, duration=4)";
        if (isIE)
        {
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 0, duration = 5).Apply();
            popUpEle.filters.revealTrans(transition = 0, duration = 5).Play();
        }
        popUpEle.style.display = "none";

    }
}

var dragApproved=false;
var DragHandler = {

    // private property.
    _oElem : null,

    // public method. Attach drag handler to an element.
    attach : function(oElem) {
        oElem.onmousedown = DragHandler._dragBegin;
        // callbacks
        oElem.dragBegin = new Function();
        oElem.drag = new Function();
        oElem.dragEnd = new Function();
        return oElem;
    },

    // private method. Begin drag process.
    _dragBegin : function(e) {

       if (!document.all)return;

        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem = this;

        if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.left))){ oElem.style.left = '0px'; }
        if (isNaN(parseInt(oElem.style.top))) { oElem.style.top = '0px'; }

        var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
        var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

        e = e ? e : window.event;

       if (e.pageX || e.pageY) 
       {
        oElem.mouseX = e.pageX;
        oElem.mouseY = e.pageY;
       }
       else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)     {
        oElem.mouseX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft+ document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        oElem.mouseY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop+ document.documentElement.scrollTop;
       }
        document.onmousemove = DragHandler._drag;
        dragApproved=true;
        document.onmouseup = DragHandler._dragEnd;  
        return false;
    },

    // private method. Drag (move) element.
    _drag : function(e) {

     if(dragApproved && event.button==1)
      {
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;

        var x = parseInt(oElem.style.left);
        var y = parseInt(oElem.style.top);

        e = e ? e : window.event;

       var clientXTmp,clientYTmp;
       if (e.pageX || e.pageY) 
       {
        clientXTmp = e.pageX;
        clientXTmp = e.pageY;
       }
       else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)     {
        clientXTmp = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft+ document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        clientYTmp = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop+ document.documentElement.scrollTop;
       }

        var tmpX = x + (clientXTmp - oElem.mouseX);
        var tmpY = y + (clientYTmp - oElem.mouseY);

        if(tmpX<=0){tmpX = 0;}
        if(tmpY<=0){tmpY = 0;}
        //Avoiding scrolling of rigth and bottom of the window
        if((tmpX+oElem.offsetWidth) > document.body.offsetWidth)
          {
            tmpX= document.body.offsetWidth-oElem.offsetWidth;
          }
         if((tmpY+oElem.offsetHeight) > document.body.offsetHeight)
          {
            tmpY= document.body.offsetHeight-oElem.offsetHeight;
          }

        oElem.style.left = tmpX + 'px';
        oElem.style.top  = tmpY + 'px';

        oElem.mouseX = clientXTmp;
        oElem.mouseY = clientYTmp;
        return false;
     }
    },

    // private method. Stop drag process.
    _dragEnd : function() 
     {
        dragApproved=false;
        var oElem = DragHandler._oElem;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        DragHandler._oElem = null;
    }
}

 DragHandler.attach(document.getElementById('popup'));
</script>
</HTML>
```